# If mysql schema is missing, where can I find credentials?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

After finding a sql injection vulnerability I need to provide the more information I can about the DB. Minimum I need to provide a list of users and passwords.

I identified that it's a MySQL but checking `information_schema.schemata` I notice there are just two databases: `information_schema` and `abc` (the one created for the problem).

`mysql` is missing, so from where can I get the list of users and passwords? As `mysql.user` is unavailable.

Comment: Your user may not have administrative access. Successful SQL injection doesn't mean full database server compromise. It just means you can inject data into the DB as that user, if you not admin you will not be able to select this data.

Comment: @DavidHoude I understand that, but at least the schema "mysql" should show up in information_schema, shouldn't it?

Comment: @DavidHoude SQL injection means you can inject SQL commands/fragments. Injecting data requires a data manipulation statement (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `REPLACE`).

Comment: There is no way for mysql to exist and not to have a "mysql" db. Your user might be blocked like stated in [this answer](http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-restrict-mysql-user-access-to-a-single-datab-1734.html).

Comment: By the way, did you receive any data from querying *information_schema*?

Comment: @DarkLighting yes, I can gather everything from information_schema. I think that my current problem is a poor wording of the question by my professor, because what he's asking better suits the second problem where there is indeed a table with users and passwords xD

Comment: And what is the question *exactly*? Don't you prefer to edit the question at once?

Comment: Are you supposed to find the DB users, or the application users. Those are 2 different access levels. Does `abc` have a users table?

Comment: **my** question was about DB users. After speaking with my professor, **his** question was poorly worded and he meant to just say which user was doing the queries, which is as simple as using `user()`. Anyway, **my** question here remains open, although I think the only possible answer is to look for a privilege escalation exploit in the DB, because as DarkLighting said, there must be some hardening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DarkLighting said in comments, the mysql schema is always available because it's part of the installation, just as information_schema.

If a user can't see the mysql DB, it means he has no privileges. Likely he has the privilege **USAGE**. So in order to be able to get the users' credentials, first the attacker should leverage some privilege escalation vulnerability to get root access, and hence, gain access to the mysql DB where the credentials are stored.